# WP7 API to Switch between ring + vibrate Vs vibrate only?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Any API which would allow to Toggle between Vibrate/Ringer Settings:

1. Ring + Vibrate
2. Vibrate only

In such a away, can change ringer state from inside an App?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no such api has been exposed to 3rd party developers

Comment: And Im guessing rightly so. A program should not take care of this, this is a user setting, and should not be overridden

Comment: absolutely - unless your app involved being able to change those :P

Comment: @stevethethread Actually, I am really wishing for an app that can toggle between ringer/vibrate.  This way, I can have critical work notifications like program errors or high-priority tickets turn on my phone's ringer while I am asleep at night (sort of like a pager).

Comment: Interesting find here.  I just set my WP7 to vibrate and set my stopwatch app to go off after 1 second.  After time was up, the runger sounded, so obviously something has control over sounds while vibrate is on.

Comment: ScheduledNotifications and Alerts override default sound settings.